Private nicknames to help with user31415926536
I tend to get all these user(number) accounts mixed up all the time. The generated gravatars don't help (much) and sometimes people change theirs.
What if I could specify that I want user12345678 displayed to me as "bob" and user23456789 as "PHP guru", just for me privately?
(To avoid things like having me attempt to ping @PHPguru the display should clearly indicate the real user ID as well somehow. Maybe like "tripleee (Bash idiot)" to indicate that tripleee is my actual account name and that "Bash idiot" is an alias I wanted to be displayed for this user? But the details can surely be left to the implementor.)

Sounds like something that might fly as a script-request if the popularity of this FR stays as it is ...

I do this for myself in a userscript, along with several other strictly text changes. While I, obviously, personally find it useful for myself, it's not something that SE can have as a general feature, as doing so would violate the CC BY-SA license, which requires that the attribution not be changed.

A fair number of services allow users to annotate their "friends" (or whatever the analogous feature for that service is) to give a bit of additional context about who they are/how you know them/etc. Personally, I'd be more open to this kind of feature if it allowed me to add private notes to user profiles that appeared somewhere near their username or perhaps in the expanded usercard. However, I think that overwriting a users' display name (even privately) is more likely to cause issues and confusion than help the majority of users.

@Makyen Surely, adding an annotation, as suggested in the parenthetical, should be fine license-wise?

@tripleee I don't see how it would be OK for what you want. You, effectively, want to change their name (i.e., how they, and only they, are represented as the author of their content). That is, IMO, very clearly changing the attribution for that specific user, which isn't permitted. SE could probably get away with adding some type of indicator of a class of users (i.e., of many users), but you're wanting something very specific to a single individual.

The CC BY-SA just says that people must be attributed by their chosen name/pseudonym. It does not say that people must not be attributed with an additional name/pseudonym. As long as the chosen name is not hidden, there shouldn't be a problem with the license.

If I would be in a situation where I would need to ping people with weird default usernames to the point where I would need to slap labels on them for identification, I'm probably being too chatty in comments. You don't need to ping the author of a post and since comments are mostly for providing feedback on a post... pinging someone should really be an exception to the rule. Except on meta of course. I'm not judging, I'm not you hence I reason this from my own perspective. But still... maybe there is a little bit of that going on.

@Gimby Just picking the first two specific users that came to mind, there are 163 posts that both user12002570 and user17732522 have commented on.  In tags I frequent, I often recognize users whom I know to be knowledgable in certain areas; this is harder if I can't reliably recognize their display name.

@Gimby My acute reason for requesting this is that I was thinking, I should not comment on this particular user's posts going forward; but how can I recognize them when their user ID and icon are completely generic?

There are other reasons to want to recognize users as well, such as recognizing patterns of problematic behavior on the site so that it can be flagged for moderator attention.  I can think of at least one case in which a user repeatedly changed their username in what was widely suspected to be an effort to avoid being recognized with the goal of getting an undeserved assumption of good faith.  Other less nefarious situations might include a user who needs advice on being friendlier in comments, appropriate use of close votes, etc.

Can't we just have a script give them random names instead of numbers? And if they don't like those then maybe get can finally be arsed to come up with a better one for themselves.

There used to be a brilliant browser addon which allowed to annotate specific users https://web.archive.org/web/20221207004522/http://bures.io/products/favorite-users/stack-exchange/ Unfortunately, SO broke it when they introduced their responsive design.

User scripts and browser add-ons are nice and all, but they are out of reach for many users (mobile users, or prohibited from installing user scripts on work computers) such as myself right now.

Tangentially, notice also how some moderators have taken to rename spam accounts to just Spammer (with variations). This helps for the specific use case of identifying the user as a spammer, but completely wrecks some others, such as trying to figure out which spam messages in metasmoke belong to this particular Spammer. (Maybe that could be fixed in metasmoke somehow, though.)

@tripleee Yes, userscripts were a stopgap measure in the absence of a build in solution. I'd love to see this feature build into SE! It would be very useful if one could add an annotation certain users, e.g, if they are the maintainer of some software. This would give me additional data when comparing multiple answers and considering which of them to try first.

@Lundin giving people random names is a slippery slope on international site. Which names we should include in the pool from which they will be taken? Should we use male or female names? What about users whose actual names are the ones in that pool, so they might now look more like being given random name instead of having their real one (if the just leave the name) Should we just use name or name and number?

@DalijaPrasnikar The point isn't to give them a name that they want to stick with, so if they get a name of the opposite gender then maybe that would encourage them to change it. We could even deliberately hand out silly, gender-neutral names, maybe on the programming theme.

@Lundin I get that, but I can also imagine a whole range of people being confused by that, if not worse. Also this does not solve the problem with existing users.

As one who has even been confused by my own numeric username I 100% agree with @DalijaPrasnikar it is a slippery slope. My current username could be interpreted as "The Empty One" as a joke (yes, it was!) but it would only work for people whose language proficiency in English was fairly good. I would be more inclined to say that usernames such as user31415926535 should be invalid and the default should be First Name and Last Name like everywhere else on the internet.

@MT1 "...  the default should be First Name and Last Name like everywhere else on the internet" cough

@MisterMiyagi - the default can be changed!

@MT1 But users don't necessarily put in a first and last name, either. Moreover, I think it would be an exceptionally bad idea to force people to reveal their real names.

Would the process of making a list of readily identifiable usernames even privately come under the scope of GDPR in some countries?

I don't see how this would be affected by GDPR. If we were able to extract the user's actual identity (or email or sexuality etc) somehow, that would be different; but here, all we are doing is add a label. If you know from another source that this user's real name is Fred J. Bloggs then it's not Stack Overflow's fault or responsibility that you are privately able to add this information.

Who cares who is truly responsible? Sue EVERYBODY!

A userscript is probably best here; for all kinds of reasons it's probably best if Stack Overflow does not track a list of nicknames given by others for users.

More efficient would be a system that only shows annotations on a user's profile page--they're much less frequently visited and it would only require one lookup per page load. It could also then allow users to write whatever they want rather than just serve as a 'nickname' option. In short, just like the moderator annotation, except per-user rather than a single shared annotation. If you think you recognize a user but aren't sure why, click through to their profile and see what you've written as an annotation.

There's no conflict with GDPR or CC-By-SA here. As far as GDPR, acting on any request could just wipe out any user-applied nicknames to be safe. As for CC-By-SA, as MisterMiyagi's comment notes, the attribution requirements only state that their preferred name must be presented, not that other names cannot be suffixed or shown in addition. Especially since this feature would be per-user, there would be no way of even knowing, let alone seeing, whether some user has decided to apply a nickname to another user's post.

If the above were a violation of CC-By-SA, then so too would a userscript that an individual ran on their own machine violate it, which is of course absurd.

This would be very expensive to implement, data-wise--you'd have to do multiple lookups every time you load a page, not just for the stored author of every post or comment on a page, but also check a table owned by a totally separate user (you) for whether any of the posts on a page are authored by users who are also in your personal nickname list. It can obviously be done, it's not that complex (Steam offers this exact feature, for example), but I don't know that it would be worth it to potentially double the number of database lookups on every page, for every visit. Still, you get my +1!
